# How can I return a property value for the first element in an array or 0 if there are no elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my HTML I have this code block:

```
<div ng-click="wos.wordWordFormRowClicked(wf)"
         ng-repeat="wf in word.wordForms">
   ...
</div>
```

The `word` object can have 0 or many `wordForms` and each `wordForm` has a property `wordFormIdentityId`.

In javascript how can I get the `wordFormIdentityId` of the first `wordForm` or return 0 if there are no wordForms. Hope this makes sense, if not please ask and I will try to explain more.

Here are the typescript interfaces:

```
interface IWord {
    wordForms: IWordForm[];
    wordId: string;
}

interface IWordForm {
    definition: string;
    wordFormId: string;
    wordFormIdentity: number;
    wordId: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something or does this handle it? I responded in Typescript as well.

```
function getFirstId (word:IWord) :number {
    if(word && word.wordForms && word.wordForms.length > 0) {
        return word.wordForms[0].wordFormIdentity;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you need in your function:

```
if(word.wordForms)
   return word.wordForms[0].wordFormIdentity || 0;
```

Comment: you should add if clauses like @Paarth answer, I just add my answer for different suggestion.